# Using an Interface as a super type for Enum classes - problem with accessing Enum-specific methods

Tags: java, generics, enums, interface, bounded-types

I've been attempting to implement an *interface* in my *enums* in order to have rules for a simulation I'm making.

I am trying to access *enum-methods* such as `values()` and `ordinal()` (on objects).

However, even with upper-bounding my classes with my interface name, I still cannot access these methods without overriding them in my interface, which won't work.

```
public interface State{
    public static void setTileSize(int size){
        return;
    }

    public void draw(PApplet app, int x, int y);

    public Object updateState(int[] allNeighbours);

    public int getColour();

}

enum WireWorld implements State{ // WireWorld
    WIRE(new Color(100, 100, 100)) {
        public WireWorld updateState(int[] allNeighbours){
            if (allNeighbours[1] >= 1){
                return TIP;
            }
            return WIRE;
        }
    }, ...
```

```
public class Tile<T extends State> {
     public Tile() {
        int enumCount = T.values().length;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call the constructor on Tile and it doesn't work.

Comment: All you know about `T` is that it must implement `State`, which is not an enum. You could do something like `<T extends Enum<T> & State>`, but that still won't let you call `values()` via the `T`. The `values()` method is implicitly added to the enum **implementation** by the compiler. It is not defined by `java.lang.Enum` abstract class. You could maybe use [`Class#getEnumConstants()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants()), but that would mean you need `Tile` to accept a `Class<T>` (where `<T extends Enum<T> & State>`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide an indication that `T` extends `Enum` as it was mentioned by *@Slaw* in the comments.

We can declare multiple type bound by chaining them using ampersand sign `&` and since `Enum` is a class it needs to be mentioned before interface `State`  ([*see*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)) :

```
public class Tile<T extends Enum<T> & State>
```

Assuming that `Tile` is meant to hold a reference to an *enum member* of type `T` and invoke methods like `ordinal()` and `name()` on it. Now compiler will allow doing that, since it knows that `T extends Enum<T>`.

And seems like your intention was to define an instance variable `enumCount` in the `Tile` class that will hold a number of *enum members*. In order to initialize it, you need to provide an instance of `Class<T>` as a parameter to the constructor. And one of the way to get access to all *enum constants* `Class<T>` is through [`EnumSet.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf(java.lang.Class)).

```
public class Tile<T extends Enum<T> & State> {
    private int enumCount;
    private T item;
    
    public Tile(Class<T> enumClass) {
        this.enumCount = EnumSet.allOf(enumClass).size();
    }
    
    public void someMethod() {
        item.ordinal(); // that will compile
        item.name();    // that will compile as well
    }
    
    // ...
}
```